Snapchat Public API Content-Type header not supported
I am attempting to make a GET request to the following endpoint:
GET https://businessapi.snapchat.com/public/v1/public_profiles/{profile_Id}/stats
However, I'm encountering difficulties with the Content-Type header. Initially, I received an error message stating that "Content-Type 'application/json' is not supported," even though the documentation specifies this as the expected Content-Type.
When I attempted to omit the Content-Type header, I received a different error stating that:

"Content-Type is missing from the request."

Additionally, setting the Content-Type to other common types such as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' or 'multipart/form-data' also resulted in errors indicating that the Content-Type is not supported.
I have thoroughly reviewed the documentation and tried various Content-Type headers, but I have not been successful in resolving this issue.
